# Quantas perguntas um usuário pode fazer em um dia?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Fiquei pensando sobre isso! Qual o total perguntas que um usuário pode fazer em um dia?

Já li aqui em um post que um usuário tinha estourado esse limite. Então qual é o limite? Fazer duas peguntas ou três perguntas em um dia já é considerado um exagero?

Comment: Não existe limite de perguntas. O sistema apenas bloqueia quando há muitas perguntas que foram "má recebidas" (votos negativos, pendentes, etc.).

Comment: Que eu saiba *há* um limite imposto recentemente. Tem que conferir se está funcionando aqui no SOpt.

Comment: @Jéferson   Obrigado, é bom saber!

Comment: @brasofilo, seria isso? [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/238766)

Comment: @brasofilo, Obrigado ajudou muito!

Comment: @rray: yes, e está atualizado recentemente, blz!

Comment: Ninguém com disposição de ajudar a traduzir esse post sobre rate limits?

Comment: Dica aos futuros leitores: se você virar um *perguntador profissional*, vai espantar os usuários mais experientes e dedicados, com certeza pode dar sorte e ter suas dúvidas respondidas, mas fica o carimbo "trabalha na base de pergunta grátis".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [Detalhamento dos Limites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32202)

### Comentários

- Votando

  - 10 sinalizações em comentários por dia ([pode ser aumentada até 100/dia](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts))
  - [30 votos ou remoção de/em comentários por dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331)
  - sem tempo mínimo entre os votos
    [image: Limite de votos diários atingido; vote novamente em 3 horas.]
- Deletando ([tratado como voto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14185))

  - sem limites
- Criando

  - [Três comentários em 30 segundos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission/251005?noredirect=1#comment819750_251005)

    [image: Você pode adicionar outro comentário em 24 segundos.]
- Editando

  - um comentário pode ser editado a cada 5 segundos por seu autor ou por um moderador com diamante
    [image: Você só pode editar um comentário a cada 5 segundos.]
  - comentários não podem ser editados após 5 minutos

### Buscando

- [Sem limites para humanos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100) é o que foi afirmado, mas [testes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches/166034#166034) demonstraram que existe um limite de 30 buscas a cada 60 segundos (veja o comentário na resposta linkada).

### Perguntando

- Usuários com reputação < 125 : 20 minutos (90 minutos no [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256323))

  - Usuário limitados pelo [Sistema Anti-Reincidência](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610): uma pergunta por semana
  - Usuários impedidos de perguntar [baseado na qualidade de suas perguntas anteriores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited): sem pergunta por 1-7 dias
- Usuários com reputação < 10k precisam resolver um captcha se perguntarem mais de uma vez dentro de 60 segundos
- Usuários com reputação > 10k precisam resolver um captcha se perguntarem mais de uma vez dentro de 30 segundos
- Nos sites Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault e Mathematics (não ativado nos outros sites):

  - máximo de 6 perguntas por dia
  - [máximo de 50 perguntas em 30 dias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217)

> Desculpe, você só pode fazer 50 perguntas em um período de 30 dias

### Respondendo

- Usuários com reputação < 100: [não podem responder suas próprias perguntas por 8 horas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86186)
- Usuários com reputação  < 125: [3 minutos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23038)
- Usuários com 125 < reputação < 10k: precisam resolver um captcha se mais de uma vez dentro de 60 segundos
- Usuários com 10k+ de reputação: precisam resolver um captcha se mais de uma vez dentro de 30 segundos
- Máximo de 30000 caracteres em respostas.
  [image: Limite de caracteres na resposta]

### Aceitando

- [Todos devem aguardar 15 minutos após a criação da pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099)
- [Todos devem aguardar 48 horas após a criação da pergunta para aceitar sua própria resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)
  [image: Tempo limite de aceitação]

### Editando

- 5 edições na própria publicação por dia, esse valor aumenta gradativamente de acordo com a reputação do usuário e não se aplica aos moderadores ♦

> Você já editou 5 de suas publicações hoje; você precisa esperar até amanhã para fazer mais edições

- 5 respostas antigas removidas por dia (não tenho certeza de que isso é contabilizado junto com as edições, a confirmar/refutar), não se aplica a ♦ moderadores
- Usuários não registrados não podem sugerir edições em publicações feitas a mais de 10 minutos
- Usuários com < 10k de reputação: precisam resolver um captcha se mais de uma vez dentro de 30 segundos ou se mais rápidos que 5 segundos após começar a edição
- Usuários com > 10k de reputação: precisam [resolver um captcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293) se mais de uma vez dentro de 10 segundos ou se mais rápidos que 5 segundos após começar a edição

### Sinalizando

- Inicialmente o limite de sinalizações por dia para qualquer usuário é de 10, esse valor pode [aumentar até 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890), de acordo com o histórico de sinalização do usuário.
- 5 segundos entre as sinalizações
- 3 segundos entre a abertura da janela de sinalização

[image: sinalizações por dia]

[image: taxa de popups de sinalizações]

[image: popup da caixa de diálogo de sinalização]

### Analisando

- [20 análises por fila por dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981), se a fila possuir menos de 1000 itens pendentes
- [40 análises por fila por dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233), se a fila possuir 1000 ou mais itens  pendentes
- Sem limites para os moderadores ♦

> Você não tem mais votos de edição sugerida por hoje; volte em x horas.

### Chat

- 1 segundo entre cada mensagem, aqui está a real curva do limite
  [image: Chat Throttle Curve]
- Existe uma curva de limite similar para favoritar (detalhes desconhecidos)
- Existe uma curva de limite similar para pesquisar (detalhes desconhecidos)
- [Limite de favoritos por usuário por dia por sala de 20](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236370).

### Votando

- 30 votos por dia +10 de bônus apenas para questões (votos bônus não podem ser usados após 25 votos dados em respostas). [Fonte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213))

### Trocando nome de usuário

- [Uma vez a cada 30 dias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180), com 15 minutos de carência. Não se aplica a moderadores ♦.
- contas com menos de 2 dias de idade podem trocar de nome a vontade

### Mostrando votos

- [um por segundo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35488)

> Você só pode buscar a contagem de votos uma vez por segundo

### Fechando

- Você pode abrir a Caixa de Diálogo de Fechamento uma vez a cada 3 segundos
- 50 votos de fechamento/reabertura por dia, por usuário no SO; 24 votos nas outras comunidades [Fonte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/13295)

[image: Close Dialog rate limit box]

### Deletando

- 5 publicações de um usuário pode ser deletada por ele mesmo no dia
- [5 votos de remover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105876) (aos 10mil) com um voto extra de remoção para cada mil de rep que exceder 10mil, até o máximo de 30 por dia
- Uma pergunta não pode ser votada para remoção até os dois dias de idade, [exceto para usuários com rep 20mil+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70044) e pontuação de [-3 ou menos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675)

### Chapéus do Winterbash

- Trocar de chapéu a cada 10 segundos

[image]

### App do iOS

- Por depender da API, um segundo entre cada ação
  [image]

---

> Traduzido de: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/229289

Comment: Wow grande resposta!

Comment: SOpt também tem chapéus?

Comment: @RSinohara tem sim, não falta muito para a época deles chegar :)