# Limites diários nas filas de aprovações ou análises

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Hoje a fila de baixa qualidade estava com muitos itens, e quando os analisados por mim somaram 20 (nem percebi, na verdade), apareceu uma mensagem dizendo que era pra voltar depois de 2 horas, mesmo ainda tendo 12 itens na fila para serem analisados.

Há limites diários nas filas? Se sim, quais os limites de cada fila?

Comment: Se não me engano são 20 analises, em algumas filas ao atingir os 40 votos diarios tbm termina o 'trabalho diario'(mesmo que não tenha feito 20 analises.

Comment: Já fui bloqueado 2 vezes na fila de baixa qualidade.

Comment: Bloqueado? ou chegou no limite de 20 analises/40 votos(up/down) ?

Comment: @rray sim, estava bloqueado por duas horas, mas a fila voltou ao normal, ai analisei 20 e nem vi de novo(a fila tava cheia demais kkk) e agora to bloqueado até amanha. Mas é só na fila de baixa qualidade, nunca vi essa fila tao cheia que nem hoje.

Answer (score 6):

Baseado nessa [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4375/91) que comenta sobre todos os limites de votos análises etc, os limite são.

20 análises por fila por dia, se a fila possuir menos de 1000 itens pendentes.

40 análises por fila por dia, se a fila possuir 1000 ou mais itens pendentes.

O trabalho diario de análises pode terminar quando você atingir os limite de votos(up/down) isso se aplica as filas de **primeira publicações** e **respotas tardias**.

Comment: É bastante limite, muitos eu nem imaginava que existiam!